# How to change what a string equals in a forloop

Tags: java, string, for-loop

EDIT: sorry i need to clarify my question, I want to change what the string animal means, first dogs then cats, so when the loop runs it will first use the string animal = dogs and the second time it will use string animal = cats

The first time the inner forloop runs, i want the string animal to equal dogs and the second time it equals cats.

so it would go something like this:

How many puzzles did dog 1 solve?

How many puzzles did dog 2 solve?

How many puzzles did dog 3 solve?

How many puzzles did dog 4 solve?

How many puzzles did cat 1 solve?

How many puzzles did cat 2 solve?

How many puzzles did cat 3 solve?

How many puzzles did cat 4 solve?

Thanks in advance

```
final int NUMANIMALS = 4;
int puzzlesSolved;       
int puzzlesTotal;
String textinput;    
String animal;  

for(int i = 1; i <=2; i++)
{
    for(int puzzleNum = 1; puzzleNum <= NUMANIMALS; puzzleNum++)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many puzzles did " +
                animal + puzzleNum + " solve?");

            puzzlesSolved = Integer.parseInt(textinput);

            if(!(puzzlesSolved >= 0 && puzzlesSolved <= 5))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Please enter a number between 0 and 5");
            } else { break; }
       }   
   }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like fun. What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `if` condition.

```
if (i == 1) {
    animal = "dog";
} else if (i == 2) {
    animal = "cat";
}
```

Some additional comments:

1. I would recommend using `Enum` instead of `String`.
2. This: `for(int puzzleNum = 1; puzzleNum <= NUMANIMALS; mazeNum++)` looks like an infinite loop to me, as your `puzzleNum` doesn't change in the loop at all.

Comment: Or even better an array of animal options, then just pick up the i-th element. That way adding duck, cow etc is easy

Comment: @RichardTingle Not really, adding duck and cow is easy when you're using `enums`. Not some array of animal options.

Comment: Enums are almost always the "even better" way but they can be a tad advanced for beginners

Comment: @RichardTingle Please, enums are "nice and easy" (and clean) solution ;) I'm sure he will understand the concept, if he already does not.